# Php - Suhosin is blocking moodle installation

Tags: php, security, centos7

I'm having problems to install moodle onto my server because of suhosin, and when i look at the suhosin logs there's stuff like this:

> Aug  8 19:23:55 dynavio suhosin[22877]: ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 536870912 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker '127.0.0.1', file '/var/www/html/moodle/lib/setuplib.php', line 1278)

,

> Aug  8 19:42:49 dynavio suhosin[7963]: ALERT - configured request variable name length limit exceeded - dropped variable '2in3/2_9_0/build/yui2-skin-sam-treeview/assets/skins/sam/yui2-skin-sam-treeview-min_css' (attacker '127.0.0.1', file '/var/www/html/moodle/theme/yui_combo.php')

and

> Aug  8 19:42:49 dynavio suhosin[7963]: ALERT - dropped 1 request variables - (1 in GET, 0 in POST, 0 in COOKIE) (attacker '127.0.0.1', file '/var/www/html/moodle/theme/yui_combo.php')

So is there a way to temporarily whitelist the moodle directory to bypass security rules or whitelist my ip address, or do i just have to go and manually change the limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `/etc/php.ini` search for the section marked

`[suhosin]`

You can then add the following:

`; Misc Options
suhosin.simulation = On`

This is equivalent to disabling it.

With this set reloading apache should apply the setting, remember to undo this after installation.

You could also make a copy of php.ini specifically for the moodle installation/VirtualHost/Domain making a more permanent "whitelist rule".

Comment: Ok, so there wasn't a [suhosin] line in the config so i added one manually. Time to see if that works.

Comment: i guess there should already be definition for that module.. mabe a seperate file in `/etc/php.d/`    could be called something like `suhosin.ini`

Comment: You're right there is a suhosin.ini file in /etc/php.d transferring the parameter to that file

Comment: Checked with `phpinfo();` and it seems the parameter is set to on.

Comment: Running through the moodle install is suhosin now allowing it to install?.. Failing that i would suggest temporarily preventing that module to load while installing moodle...this can be done by renaming that module definition file. `mv /etc/php.d/suhosin.ini /etc/php.d/suhosin.ini.disabled`

Comment: I don't know yet, as i'm resetting the moodle files. That takes a while.

Comment: Ok, let me know, good luck.

Comment: Just one more question, would it be possible to disable suhosin for the moodle directory using a .htaccess file?

Comment: yeah i guess adding a php flag to the `.htaccess` file would do it, something like `php_flag suhosin.simulation On`  would enable the simulation mode (logging but not enforcing),  i don't believe there is a way to entirely disable the module on a per site basis. You could look into a seperate apache instance but that would require a different port (besides 80)